# reloadData from UITableViw does not work

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, tableview

I`m developing an in-app purchase app and after get the products pro app store I'm trying to load those products in a uitableview. The problem is: when I get the product list I cannot load the data inside the table. When I create the table using static values and without using reloadData everything works.

Eeverything is working fine beside load the table

where's my code:

```
@synthesize products;
@synthesize productsTableView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    NSSet *productIndentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"Prod01",@"Prod02",@"Prod03",nil];
    productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIndentifiers];
    [productsRequest start];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:TRUE];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setProductsTableView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return self.products.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    [self.productsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
        SKProduct *product = [self.products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = product.localizedTitle;

    }

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - SKProductsRequestDelegate 

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"%@", response.products);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:FALSE];
    [self.productsTableView reloadData];

}


- (void)dealloc {
    [productsTableView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed adding result of SKProductsRequest  to self.products

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"%@", response.products);
self.product = assign data here
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:FALSE];
    [self.productsTableView reloadData];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have data not locally but on some server you should be using this imo.

> [tableView beginUpdate];
>         [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:*arrayOfIndexPaths* withRowAnimation:*rowAnimation*];
>          [tableView endUpdate];

Also, I wanted to point out that your cell reuse identifiers are wrong In one case you have "Cell" and in the other case you have "MyCell"

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems. NeverBe and S.P. have noted some.  Here is another major one.

One problem is in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

You are only setting data in the cell when its new.  The table view recycles cells, so some will skip your if statement.  Those will not get setup properly.  Move your cell setup outside of the if statement.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {   

        UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
        [self.productsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        if(cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

        }

        SKProduct *product = [self.products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = product.localizedTitle;

        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, probable a was having another problem and when I fixed it I removed the products array attribution.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see that's a bit strange is that your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: routine references self.productsTableView. But you're already *in* a tableView -- why does your tableView contain a reference to *another* tableView? That's odd.

As well, have you checked that self.products actually contains products where it's referenced in both tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: and tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:? I can't tell since you don't show any code showing where that ivar is set. Throw in an NSLog() statement or put a breakpoint and make sure it really contains what you think it does.